# How does gradle execute an ant build file

Tags: android, ant, gradle, build-process

Ive been driving myself crazy trying to rebuild my custom_rules.xml into something in gradle and its proving to be quite difficult. So my next step is Im trying to just import the last few things I cant do in gradle as an build.xml.

However this doesnt seem to do anything. When I try using
    ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
I get no feed back or no echos from my script. Ive read through gradles documentation a lot especially on ant and for the life of me I cant figure out what Im supposed to do once the build gets imported. How does the script get executed?

This is my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
<target name="postPackage" >
<property name="config_path" location="${cert.dir}" />
<property name="out.pre.widevine.signed.file" location="release-pre-widevine-sign.apk" />
<property name="out.widevine.signed.file" location="release-widevine-signed.apk" />
<echo>sign with widevine certificate</echo>
<touch file="res/raw/wv.properties"/>
<copy file="${out.packaged.file}" tofile="${out.pre.widevine.signed.file}"/>
<java jar="apksigtool.jar" failonerror="true" fork="true">
    <arg value="${out.packaged.file}"/>
    <arg value="private_key.der" />
    <arg value="my.crt" />
</java>
<copy file="${out.packaged.file}" tofile="${out.widevine.signed.file}"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using the following snippet in a method

```
    ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
    postPackage.doFirst{println("Im starting")}
    postPackage.execute()
```

Comment: That's definitely not what you want.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser Ok please suggest a better way with an actual working piece of code as a sample.

Comment: As I said, you'd first have to refine the question: what exactly does the Ant code do, when exactly should it get executed, what exactly did you try to solve the problem on the Gradle side, etc..

Comment: My final solution for this is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26048396/best-way-to-sign-an-apk-using-ant-in-a-build-gradle-file

Answer (score 0):

`ant.importBuild` will create an equally named Gradle task for each Ant target found in the Ant build. You can then invoke those tasks from the command line and/or make other tasks depend on them. For more information, see "16.2. Importing an Ant build" in the [Gradle User Guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N11405),

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) Im working in android studio and the less time I spend on the command line means more time doing other things. So if I understand correctly, when I import my build file all the targets become tasks? Im still learing the build.gradle lifecycle so could you please explain when and where I should implement the target/task dependencies. Ive read through a lot of the documentation and its left me with a lot more questions than when I started.

Comment: That's a new question, and the current question doesn't contain enough information to answer that. Either edit the question or create a new one.

Comment: RFM responses are limited in their usefulness.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think this Kotlin is working for me;

```kotlin
  val t : Task = tasks.named("war").get()
  t.actions.forEach { a -> a.execute(t) }
```

Comment: Note this was my earlier answer and doesn't seem to work 
gradle.run { tasks.getByName("war") }